# How can I get color panel icons in Lubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, icons, lubuntu, lxpanel

How do I get all color panel icons in Lubuntu 12.04? I have tried changing the "look and feel" and the openbox settings, but there doesn't seem to be any way to get all color panel icons.[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you mean by "all color". Also, if you could describe your current situation or put up an image somewhere and provide the link here that would help people understand your problem better.

Comment: i guess you mean the same color or different colors for the icons -- that is done by changing the icon set in "Customize look and feel". but it also depends on the programs displayed on the panel and in the tray

Answer (score 0):

In Main Menu - Preferences - Customize look and feel - Icon theme

[image]

To get new icons look on sites like [gnome-look.org](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=120x121&PHPSESSID=8981c411f9832bc8761fa9e957c8d25b) or [noobslab.com](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/11/themes-collection-for-ubuntu-1110-unity.html#icons).